# Numerically Finding Number of Roots in an Interval of a Smooth Function involving Floor Function

Tags: complex-analysis, roots, ceiling-and-floor-functions, smooth-functions

For a lot of smooth functions, you could use the [Argument Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_principle). However, those only work for holomorphic functions. Functions with the floor function are not holomorphic. So, given a smooth function that uses the floor function, is there a method similar to the Argument Principle, that can numerically tell the number of roots of the function in an interval?

Comment: Even without the floor function, compare $y=x^2+0.01$ with $y=x^2-0.01$ over $(-1,1)$.  The first has no roots, the second has two.  Any solution to your problem has to deal with this.  It is hard in the reals because you don't get the constraints that holomorphic functions have in the complex plane.

Comment: @RossMillikan Both functions are holomorphic, no? I don't see the problem.

Comment: @QuoteDave And both are polynomials, for which the problem is solved by [a fairly efficient algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-root_isolation#Vincent's_and_related_theorems). However, 'uses floor function' is too general. You could make any function 'use' the floor function.

Comment: My point is that they are very similar in the reals.  If you have the complex plane available they are less similar because the roots  of one are real and the other complex.  You speak of an interval, which makes me think you are working in the reals.  In that case, distinguishing functions which almost touch the axis from those that cross is hard.

Comment: @RossMillikan Actually, I did a test using both polynomials and the principle and it was fairly accurate: $-6.867836091436453e^{-15}-4.45093739043419e^{-15}j$ for $x^2+0.01$ and $2.0000000000000195+1.9992994995879638e^{-16}j$ for $x^2-0.01$ in $(-1,1)$.

Comment: Those values are not correct.  The roots of $x^2+0.01$ are $\pm 0.1j$ and the roots of $x^2-0.01$ are $\pm0.1$  With the precision of $64$ bit floats those are easy to tell apart.  The idea that a function can come close to the axis is still valid and such functions will lead to difficulties.  You just need to be much closer for there to be a problem.

Comment: @RossMillikan No, no, I edited my program so that only the real roots will be counted (busing an ellipse that encompasses the range on the real axis but, has a low radius on the imaginary axis, so it won't count roots like $\pm 0.1j$.

Comment: You can solve these quadratics by hand easily and verify that my roots are correct.  Your root for $x^2+0.01$ is essentially $0$, so the value is about $0.01$.  Your root for $x^2-0.01$ is $2$, where the value is $4$.  Something is wrong with your program.

Comment: @RossMillikan I'm confused. What my output essentially shows is that $x^2+0.01$ has no real roots in $(-1,1)$, while $x^2-0.01$ has two roots in $(-1,1)$. Is that not correct?

Comment: I thought the output was supposed to be the roots, not the number of roots.  Why is the number of roots complex, not integer?

Comment: @RossMillikan Oh, I was using the Argument Principle, which gives a complex answer.